# Angular: ngrx subscribe doesn't update the view

Tags: angular, redux

I can't find the error, the design  redux works fine and update correctly the variable. 
console.log(this.count) works, but  the subscribe doesn't update the view {{ count }}

Many thanks.

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromContador from '../logic.actions';
import { AppState } from '../app.reducer';

export class InputsComponent {

      count: number;

      constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {

            this.store.select('count').subscribe(function(contador){

                   this.count= count;
                   console.log("count:" +  this.count);

            });                      
      }
```

Comment: You're updating `this.contador`, not `this.count`?

Comment: sorry i've made a mistake, I 've update the code.

Comment: You are using `function` in the callback. That's the problem.

Comment: @eko , of course i am using a function in the callback what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: @Gelso77 You need to use arrow functions, otherwise you lose the context of `this`.

Comment: @Gelso77 please read the question and the answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: Thanks it works, I've solved to add  .bind(this);